# Executing Python through NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js

Purpose:
Execute python machine learning models from an existing NodeJS api

So Far:
I've written a small class to handle spawning and keeping child processes alive.
I can spin up, execute, and return results from the python process, however it seems oddly slow. After some profiling I've discovered that < 18ms are spent in the python code, but the time from calling `execute()` to `callback(result)` takes > 500ms.

Does the `end` event just take a long time to fire? Any suggestions are helpful!

**Class:**

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

class PythonRunner {
    constructor(opts) {
        this.py = {};
        this.script = opts[0].script;
        this.py.process = spawn('python', [opts[0].script]);
    }


    /*
    time leak in execute is between write and .on(data);
    */

    execute(args, callback) {
        console.time('execute');
        args = JSON.stringify(args);
        let result = '';
        this.py.process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            // console.log(data.toString());
            result += data.toString();
        });
        this.py.process.stdout.on('end', () => {
            console.timeEnd('execute');
            this.py.process = spawn('python', [this.script]);
            callback(result)
        });
        this.py.process.stdin.write(`${args}`);
        this.py.process.stdin.end();
    }
}

module.exports = PythonRunner;
```

**Execution Code:**

```
let Runner = require('../index');


let args = [8, 6, 22.92, 144.163, 3, 22.92, 498.562, 130.6713, -25.457, -26.1477, 22.92, 54, 101.166666666667, 4.52941176470588, 19.1995473684211, 23.81, -27.2147, 2.424, 2.472, 2.389]
let options = [
    { name: 'somePythonModel', script: './__pycache__/SOME_PYTHON_MODEL.cpython-36.pyc', args: args }
];


let script = new Runner(options);

(function executeAgain() {
    script.execute(args, (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        executeAgain();
    });
})();
```

**Results from time profiling:** (read_in(), model_score(), and main() are all within the python code)

```
execute: 538.514ms
read_in(): 0.030994ms
model_score(): 17.854929ms
main(): 17.935991ms

execute: 539.759ms
read_in(): 0.027895ms
model_score(): 18.370152ms
main(): 18.446922ms

execute: 545.662ms
read_in(): 0.030994ms
model_score(): 18.548965ms
main(): 18.632889ms
```

Comment: if your're on linux try comparing the results with `time` and report back

Comment: Can you please explain further? @zython

Comment: well linux has a `time` command, it measures the time of the task given as the argument to it (time sleep 1, will spit out that it took 1 sec), my proposal would be to see if you can narrow down the delay to nodes fault of pythons fault

Comment: I've narrowed it down to node. I've run the python process on it's own and execution time is ~18ms; when running the python process from node, the python execution time is the same, but the return to node is slower than expected

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7652 found this maybe this is helpful ?

Comment: Thanks for the link but I'm already calling `this.py.process.stdin.end();` (the presented work around in that thread)